# Octals 302 240 together seem to correspond to non-breaking space

Tags: character-encoding, whitespace, od

By looking at a particular line of a text file (say, the 1123th, see below), it seems that there is a non-breaking space, but I am not sure:

```
$ cat myfile.csv | sed -n 1123p | cut -f2
Lisztes feher

$ cat myfile.csv | sed -n 1123p | cut -f2 | od -An -c -b
   L   i   s   z   t   e   s 302 240   f   e   h   e   r  \n
 114 151 163 172 164 145 163 302 240 146 145 150 145 162 012
```

However, the [ASCII code](http://ascii-code.com/) in octal indicates that a non-breaking space is 240. So what does the 302 correspond to? Is it something particular to this given file?

I am asking the question in order to understand. I already know how to use `sed` to fix my problem, following this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/517852/65225):

```
$ cat myfile.csv | sed -n 1123p | cut -f2 | sed 's/\xC2\xA0/ /g' | od -An -c -b
   L   i   s   z   t   e   s       f   e   h   e   r  \n
 114 151 163 172 164 145 163 040 146 145 150 145 162 012
```

For information, the original file is in the .xlsx ([Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel)) format. As my computer runs [Xubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu), I opened it with [LibreOffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice) Calc (v5.1). Then, I saved it as "Text CSV" with "Character set = Unicode (UTF-8)" and tab as field separator:

```
$ file myfile.csv
myfile.csv: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Comment: Did you really have to use octal? Hex is many times easier to work with. I haven't used octal since 1979.

Comment: @EJP I used octal because initially I had a hard time understanding the output of `od -x`, which is often advised on Internet but corresponds to hexadecimal 2-byte units. But after your comment, by re-reading the man page of `od` more thoroughly, I realized that using `od -c -t x1` was indeed maybe better.

Comment: @user207421 : have you ever looked at the `UTF-8` multi-byte encodings ? for a sizable portion of code points, simply concat the 2nd and 3rd octal digit for each byte, and that's usually the octal code of the underlying code point itself. it's far easier to read than a bunch of hex, esp for UTF-8. The 1st octal digit is also extremely informative - most 3s represent a multi-byte leading byte, 2 is a continuation byte ( the `0x80-0xBF`), and either 1 or 0 is good ole `ASCII`, with all the letters, both upper case and lower case, in the 1xx zone.

Comment: - that's so much cleaner than 7F 80 BF C2 F5. I use hex for the code points, but then use octals for the bytes themselves to make a clean differentiation in my workflows.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's the UTF-8 encoding of the U+00A0 Unicode character:

```
$ unicode U+00A0
U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE
UTF-8: c2 a0 UTF-16BE: 00a0 Decimal: &#160; Octal: \0240
 
Category: Zs (Separator, Space)
Bidi: CS (Common Number Separator)
Decomposition: <noBreak> 0020

$ locale charmap
UTF-8
$ printf '\ua0' | od -to1
0000000 302 240
0000002
```

UTF-8 is an encoding of Unicode with a variable number of bytes per character. Unicode as a charset is a superset of iso8859-1 (aka latin1) itself a superset of ASCII.

While in iso8859-1, the non-breaking-space character (codepoint 0xa0 in iso8859-1 like in Unicode) would be expressed as a one 0xa0 byte, in UTF-8, only code points 0 to 127 are expressed as one byte (which makes UTF-8 a superset of ASCII or in other words ASCII files are also UTF-8 files).

Code points over 128 are encoded with more bytes per characters. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for details of the UTF-8 encoding algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

302 240 is the combination of <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>.

On a french keyboard when you want to type a space after a `|` it's easy to type <kbd>Alt-gr</kbd> + <kbd>|</kbd>  <kbd>Alt-gr</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>  when you wanted <kbd>Alt-gr</kbd> + <kbd>|</kbd>  <kbd>space</kbd> and then you get an error.